# Require file emitted by webpack plugin through compilation.assets[] =

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am using the [webpack-free-tex-packer](https://github.com/odrick/webpack-free-tex-packer) plugin to pack a bunch of images into atlases with these lines in `webpack.config.js`:

```js
...
plugins: [
    new WebpackFreeTexPacker(path.resolve(__dirname, 'textures'), 'atlases', {
        textureName: 'atlas',
        width: 512, height: 512,
        padding: 1,
        allowRotation: false, allowTrim: false,
        detectIdentical: true,
        exporter: "Pixi",
    }),
],
```

which in turn emits the generated atlases [here](https://github.com/odrick/webpack-free-tex-packer/blob/362a8ce861bf2581b126a048d4f6a58b69af3849/index.js#L172) through setting properties on `compilation.assets`. This works and the outputs get shows up when building:

```
atlases/atlas-0.json   1.51 KiB          [emitted]
 atlases/atlas-0.png   32.6 KiB          [emitted]
atlases/atlas-1.json  689 bytes          [emitted]
 atlases/atlas-1.png   3.03 KiB          [emitted]
```

**However how would I now go about importing the generated JSON files from a JavaScript module?**

I have tried to do

```js
const atlases = {};
const r = require.context('../atlases/', false, /^atlas-\d+\.json$/);
r.keys().forEach(key => atlases[key] = r(key));
```

(along with any other combination of import method and `'atlases/'` instead of the relative path), but I get the error

```
ERROR in ./src/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../atlases/' in '/home/axel/git/project/src'
 @ ./src/main.js 38:8-66
```

Comment: I'm not sure it out of the `box` supports `.json`.
https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/

Comment: Can you share the the full webpack config and structure of repo?

Comment: @tmhao2005 Yes, it is at https://github.com/axelf4/pokemon/tree/tex-packer

Answer (score 0):

I think that's impossible to use `require.context` to load all built JSON files here since `webpack` will help you to look up the files on the disk as it runs build which means it requires the files existed at that time but we have only built JSON files after it has finished building.

So I think you can load the JSON built files over http in your assets dir as an example of that repo did to view the JSON file:

```html
<div>
  <object type="application/json" data="assets/atlas.json" />
</div>
```